# How to mock a class with loops and asynchronous methods

Tags: java, asynchronous, mockito

How would I go about mocking the class USBConnection with mockito when I have asynchronous methods, threads and loops?
The basic idea behind this prorotype is that the USBConnection should send data to the variable speed in Arduino.class every second and Arduino prints out the value every second.

The class USBConnection is the one I want to mock. Any tips and guidelines to achieve this is appreciated.

```
public abstract class Arduino {

private static int speed;

public static void setSpeed(int a) {
    speed = a;
}

public static int getSpeed(){
    return speed;
}

public static void printSpeed(){
    System.out.println(speed);  
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    USBConnection usb = new USBConnection();
    Thread usbThread = new Thread(usb);
    usbThread.start();

    while(true){
        printSpeed();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}}
```

the interface

```
interface USB {
 public void sendSpeed(int a);    }
```

the class we need to mock:

```
class USBConnection implements Runnable, USB {

public void sendSpeed(int a){
    Arduino.setSpeed(a);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while(true){            
        sendSpeed(i);
        i++;            
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Instead of mocking, wouldn't it be easier to just write a class to mimic the behavior?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is one way that could work.. but I am in the process of learning mockito for a project at school so I want to try this by mocking with mockito so I get the hang of it. So its a requriement for me to do it that way.

Comment: So then the question becomes what do you expect the mock to do? If you're needing to sleep every second, you still need to implement a method that calls Thread.sleep(1000).

FYI, your main method isn't thread safe and you could potentially print speeds multiple times or not print speeds at all.You should consider printing to console every time Arduino.setSpeed(a) is called instead of every second. Look up the Observer pattern for an idea of how this works.

Comment: Not to mention, you need this class to run in another thread, right? How are you going to achieve that with mocking?

Answer (score 0):

Based on some trial and error and Christoper's comments I decided to not use mockito in this way mentioned above.

We redesigned the software architecture and wont mock the class with loops or threads.